# WPF DataGridTextColumn doesn't scroll properly on long multiline text

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have WPF datagrid databinded to an object `List<>`. The issue is one of the `DataGridTextColumn` cells have a long multi-line text and the vertical scroll bar doesn't let me scroll through the content of the specific cell instead I can only scroll to the next cell. Have anyone encountered this issue? The code look something like below:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*">
      <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
          <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
             <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
          </Style>
      </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
      <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
          <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="true" />
          </Style>
      </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Maybe an alternative method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my workaround which is to use dataTemplate. The dataTemplate then contain the TextBox control with the attribute ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll and ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility set.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="150" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"></TextBox>
         </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```